# "Assault" vs. "Attack" in context

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, comparison

This is a statement about Switzerland that I have read somewhere in this site:

> Not all countries are as small and as filled with impassable mountains. A **seaborne assault** on Switzerland is quite difficult.

I searched dictionaries for *assault* and found it is one synonym of *attack*, but not as general as *attack* is:

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assault):

> 1. A violent physical or verbal attack.
>
> 2.
>
> a. A military attack, such as one launched against a fortified area or place.
>
> b. The concluding stage of an attack in which close combat occurs with the enemy.
>
> 3.
>   law:
>
> a. An unlawful threat or attempt to do bodily injury to another.
>
> b. The act or an instance of unlawfully threatening or attempting to injure another.
>
> 4.
>
> a. Law Sexual assault.
>
> b. The crime of rape.

Is *assault* the the most natural choice for this context? If not, why not, and which word would native readers of English prefer instead?

Comment: An attack assumes there is a war. If there isn't a war then cry attack and maybe one will have the beginnings of one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A seaborne assault* slithers smoothly off the tongue. All those sibilants! *A seaborne attack* jangles the nerves just a jot. For meaning, either one is fine. For sound, *assault* is definitely more musical and, IMHO, much better. Just an aesthetic choice by the writer.

Comment: So it is just different when you hear it not when you read it. Right?

Comment: When I read it, I hear it. Don't you hear Farsi when you read it? But good writers consider the sound of what they write. Too much [assonance or consonance, too much alliteration](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_assonance_and_consonance) turns the writing into a joke. I prefer "_assault_" in writing & speech.

Comment: Sure! I got it. And thanks for the edit too but just one question: in my own text I wrote: "not too general as attack is" and you changed it to "as general as attack is". Surely I know the rule of "as adjective as". Was my own sentence wrong grammatically or is it just a better choice to sound more natural and professional?

Comment: @Persian: It'd have to be "not **so** general as" or "not **as** general as". What you wrote is grammatically incorrect, yes. Maybe it would work if it were: "It's one synonym of _attack_, but not **too general,** as _attack_ is". This might be considered grammatical because of the added comma, but it's a bit awkward, I think, because so much is elided, & it sounds too staccato (to me) to read well.

Answer (score 1):

The two words can be used interchangeably unless there is a specific style or legal convention imposed. In casual conversation or writing there is no such convention.

I've read a number of military history books, and the choice of assault versus attack seems to be a style choice of the author. The choice seems to be based on the size of the element that is doing the assaulting or attacking. A small unit like a platoon or squad is often described as assaulting its objective. A larger unit like a battalion is often described as attacking its objective. But they do interchange to words depends on how it sounds, and to avoid the tedium of using the same word all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also describe a seaborne assault as an amphibious assault. See this http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/amphibious+assault

Answer (score 0):

In military terms, an attack is any violent action, such as shooting or engaging an enemy. I can attack an enemy position by shooting at it. An assault is a violent action in which I engage the enemy in his own position by means of close combat or hand-to-hand combat. So an assault would be correct in that forces are moving into the position in which they are attacking. Clear enough?